# Kubernetes pods running on worker node are not accessible through master node IP

Tags: kubernetes

I have one master node and two worker node

```
NAME                          STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
evosfncll232.openstacklocal   Ready    <none>                 16h   v1.21.0
evosfncll233.openstacklocal   Ready    <none>                 16h   v1.21.0
evosfncll584.ad.infosys.com   Ready    control-plane,master   25d   v1.21.0`
```

I have deployed service running on evosfncll232.openstacklocal(worker node)

```
NAME                                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP               NODE                          NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
wms-balance-deployment-585fc9df4-s46jb                1/1     Running   0          175m   10.240.72.68     evosfncll232.openstacklocal   <none>           <none>`
```

And I am using nodeport service

```
wms-balance-service               NodePort    10.111.30.104   <none>        8081:30000/TCP   176m
```

When I try to access pod using worker ip, I am able to access

```
curl http://10.73.14.40:30000/swagger -v
Uses proxy env variable no_proxy == 'evdtr.ad.infosys.com '
   Trying 10.73.14.40...
 TCP_NODELAY set
 Connected to 10.73.14.40 (10.73.14.40) port 30000 (#0)
 GET /swagger HTTP/1.1
 Host: 10.73.14.40:30000
 User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
 Accept: */*

 HTTP/1.1 302
 Location: http://10.73.14.40:30000/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
 Content-Language: en-US
 Content-Length: 0
 Date: Tue, 18 May 2021 07:32:42 GMT

 Connection #0 to host 10.73.14.40 left intact`
```

But when I try to access using master IP, it doesn't work

```
curl http://10.73.91.189:30000/swagger -v
Uses proxy env variable no_proxy == 'evdtr.ad.infosys.com '
   Trying 10.73.91.189...
 TCP_NODELAY set`
```

I have installed calico and it is up and running
`kubectl get pods -n kube-system`:

```
NAME                                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
calico-kube-controllers-655cbdf5bb-jnm9v              1/1     Running   0          23m
calico-node-rrhq9                                     1/1     Running   0          23m
calico-node-wm8xp                                     1/1     Running   0          23m
calico-node-zx457                                     1/1     Running   0          23m
coredns-5c789d5d66-5vck4                              1/1     Running   0          80m
coredns-5c789d5d66-mrlf2                              1/1     Running   0          79m
coredns-5c789d5d66-p6fz5                              1/1     Running   0          80m
etcd-evosfncll584.ad.infosys.com                      1/1     Running   8          26d
kube-apiserver-evosfncll584.ad.infosys.com            1/1     Running   10         4d13h
kube-controller-manager-evosfncll584.ad.infosys.com   1/1     Running   8          26d
kube-proxy-j8znq                                      1/1     Running   0          16h
kube-proxy-pcqst                                      1/1     Running   8          25d
kube-proxy-zjkhc                                      1/1     Running   0          16h
kube-scheduler-evosfncll584.ad.infosys.com            1/1     Running   9          25d
```

How can I access pod from master IP?

Comment: Try going through [Debug Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/) article and see if it helps you find a solution.

Comment: If services of any kind are not working, the first candidate to blame is kube-proxy. I see one of the 3 kube-proxy pods has an high number of restarts. Is it the one running on the master node? You should check the logs for that pod.

Comment: Have you found the solution for this. I am facing exactly the same issue.